Hibernate Gentoo after update does not work
I have a problem with hibernating my computer.
Everything was working before an update.
The update installed Plasma 6 and =x11-drivers/nvidia-drivers-550.127.05-r1. The kernel has not been updated.
After the update, the following command does nothing:
$ loginctl hibernate

When I trace it using ltrace, I get the following output:
$ ltrace loginctl hibernate
setlocale(LC_ALL, "")                                                                                                = "C"
elogind_set_program_name(0x7fffb8445a2d, 0x7f266b11bde0, 1, 0)                                                       = 0x7f266b135e08
log_setup(0x7fffb8445a2d, 0x7f266b11bde0, 1, 0)                                                                      = 0
rlimit_nofile_bump(0x80000, 0x7fffb84452c0, 11, 0x7f266b0a9874)                                                      = 0
sigbus_install(0, 7, 0, 0x8000000000000000)                                                                          = 0
getopt_long(2, 0x7fffb8445538, "hp:P:als:H:M:n:o:ci", 0x55aa2480b200, nil)                                           = -1
bus_connect_transport(0, 0, 0, 0x7fffb84453e0)                                                                       = 0
sd_bus_set_allow_interactive_authorization(0x55aa2482a2a0, 1, 128, 0x7f266b0a928b)                                   = 0
dispatch_verb(2, 0x7fffb8445538, 0x55aa2480b560, 0x55aa2482a2a0 <unfinished ...>
strcmp("halt", "hibernate")                                                                                          = -8
strcmp("poweroff", "hibernate")                                                                                      = 8
strcmp("reboot", "hibernate")                                                                                        = 10
strcmp("kexec", "hibernate")                                                                                         = 3
strcmp("suspend", "hibernate")                                                                                       = 11
strcmp("hibernate", "hibernate")                                                                                     = 0
geteuid()                                                                                                            = 1000
on_tty(0x55aa248068c5, 0x7fffb8445a36, 0x55aa2482a2a0, 0x7f266b07986b)                                               = 1
sd_bus_call_method(0x55aa2482a2a0, 0x55aa24806046, 0x55aa2480602e, 0x55aa24807968)                                   = 0xffffff92
polkit_agent_open_if_enabled(0, 1, 0x55aa24808270, 785)                                                              = 0
log_get_max_level(5, 0, 0, 0x7f266b096094)                                                                           = 6
sd_bus_call_method(0x55aa2482a2a0, 0x55aa24806046, 0x55aa2480602e, 0x55aa24807968)                                   = 0xffffff92
log_get_max_level(0x55aa2482a010, 0x55aa2482cd40, 0, 785)                                                            = 6
memset(0x7fffb8444f90, '\0', 1024)                                                                                   = 0x7fffb8444f90
_bus_error_message(0x7fffb8444f70, 0xffffff92, 0x7fffb8444f90, 0x7fffb8444f90)                                       = 0x7f266b13520d
log_internal(3, 0xffffff92, 0x55aa24807b89, 366)                                                                     = 0xffffff92
sd_bus_error_free(0x7fffb8444f70, 0x7fffb84443c0, 0, 0x7fffb8444f68)                                                 = 0
<... dispatch_verb resumed> )                                                                                        = 0xffffff92
polkit_agent_close(0x7fffb8444f70, 0x7fffb84443c0, 0, 0x7fffb8444f68 <no return ...>
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) ---
<... polkit_agent_close resumed> )                                                                                   = 0
strv_free(0, 0xfd6b, 0, 0x7f266b091343)                                                                              = 0
sd_bus_flush_close_unref(0x55aa2482a2a0, 0xfd6b, 0, 0x7f266b091343)                                                  = 0
sd_notifyf(0, 0x55aa24806720, 110, 0x7f266b172b20)                                                                   = 0
polkit_agent_close(0x55aa2482a010, 0x55aa2482bf80, 0x55af7e20817b, 33)                                               = 0
pager_close(0, 0x55aa2482bf80, 0x55af7e20817b, 33)                                                                   = 0
mac_selinux_finish(0, 0x55aa2482bf80, 0x55af7e20817b, 33)                                                            = 0
+++ exited (status 1) +++

Any idea where the problem might be? Everything was working before that update. Hibernating from the start menu doesn't work either.
Syslog prints this:
# grep loginctl /var/log/everything/current 
Nov 17 09:47:44 [loginctl] Failed to hibernate system via elogind: Connection timed out

What currently goes wrong? The computer does not hibernate.
EDIT:
The command echo disk > /sys/power/state also does not hibernate, although cat /sys/power/state prints freeze mem disk.

@MarcusMüller Edited the question. Simply, the command returns to the shell. The computer does not hibernate.

nice, thanks! When you run journalctl -xef in a separate terminal, while you try to hibernate, do you get output? (That might also be very helpful?)

@MarcusMüller # journalctl -xef gives -bash: journalctl: command not found. It is Gentoo. There is not journalctl.

pretty sure that if you have loginctl you also have journalctl, because to the best of my knowledge, loginctl depends on journald for logging, and journalctl is the frontend to that :) But I don't have a "reasonably default-setup" Gentoo at hand to try, so I must ask you to try and figure out how to run journalctl – having the logs of what happens when you try to hibernate is almost certainly the key to figuring out what goes wrong.

loginctl is part of elogind package (https://github.com/elogind/elogind). I guess that journalctl is part of systemd package. My system is systemd-less. I use OpenRC instead.

You must add such crucial information such as "I'm using a fork of loginctl instead of the usual systemd logind" to your question if it is centrally about loginctl (honestly, I haven't hibernated a non-systemd system in a long time – for good reason; the dependency ordering and hooking that is systemd's strength is really pretty critical there. I'm sure it works with an OpenRC system somehow, but you have to realize you need to warn your audience that you're using the minority system :)

anyways, now you need to figure out whether the kernel logs contain something, and how elogind logs things – can't help you, I'm afraid.

loginctl hibernate writes to /sys/power/state but OP said it also doesn't work so I'd check the kernel log. Maybe swap partition/file does not exist or is too small.

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk The kernel log says nothing (not even a line). The swap partition is large enough. Everything worked fine, until the update.

run dmesg -w in a separate window when running loginctl hibernate. And what does cat /sys/power/disk show?

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk running dmesg -w does not produce even a line whe do I run loginctl hibernate. However, cat /sys/power/disk now prints [platform] shutdown reboot suspend test_resume. Before I while cat /sys/power/disk given freeze mem disk.

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk See EDIT section in my question.

Everything seems to be caused by wayland running on top of the nvidia drivers. Hibernation works for me with X11.

Possible Solution
Read or Reread Gentoo Wiki: NVIDIA/nvidia-drivers. Specifically check the following:

Ensure -symlink is set in /etc/portage/make.conf
Verify that uname -a matches the selected kernel from eselect kernel
If using KDE, wayland cannot be disabled. Personal preferece is to enable it anyway, as DE development is all going towards Wayland

I am a KDE user on Gentoo, with NVIDIA graphics.


Ensure all the proper kernel options are set. <== Section 3.2 of Wiki Document
Consider using the kernel-open USE Flag and the ~arch version of the driver
Enable the nvidia-uvm (Unified Video Memory) module. See the troubleshooting section RE: Plymouth.

